# Support the European numbered list style

Tags: feature-request, design, internationalization, localization

In Europe, the way of writing, and reading, numbered lists many people are used to is with a parenthesis rather than a dot (`.`):

```
1) number 1
2) number 2
3) ...
```

instead of:

```
1. number 1
2. number 2
3. ...
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Usage_in_enumerations

It would be very nice if Stack Overflow would support this norm in two ways:

1) Support that in Markdown so that one can write it the first way.
 2) Depending on the user's browser preferences, show the list that way.

```
ol {
    counter-reset: list;
}
ol > li {
    list-style: none;
}
ol > li:before {
    content: counter(list) ") ";
    counter-increment: list;
}
```

It would be a bit more (European) user friendly.

If you are considering it from the point of view of someone accustomed to dots, imagine how it would be for you if you had to write it the other way every time you come to Stack Overflow :)  Other webs and software support that - Google Docs, [LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/3.3/Writer/Creating_Numbered_or_Bulleted_Lists_as_You_Type), MS Office... it's really a common thing.

Comment: While it's hard to imagine any problems with this particular suggestion...  rendering content differently depending on user preferences is a slippery slope one shouldn't enter without really good reason. Is this really a European vs. Anglo thing rather than a question of preference? I've used both forms interchangeably my entire life, and seen them used interchangeably, across at least four cultures.

Comment: I've used parentheses, dots, dashes, and probably a few more symbols than I should have. From Madrid, Spain, I do not see this numbered list style as a "European style". But even if it were, I'd see absolutely no gain from this.

Comment: As a European resident, I prefer `.` over `)`.

Comment: If the display is based on browser settings, that would (presumably) mean the display could be different for the person who wrote it (meaning you write and want a `.`, but yet you see a `)`) - that would be a much worse UI experience than needing to stick to one or the other.

Comment: Europeans can't even agree whether you are asking for a parenthesis or a bracket.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's just a "German-and-former-austro-hungarian" style :)

Comment: @HansPassant, parenthesis is a bracket.

Comment: @Dukeling, I don't think so. If you write a list like 1. 1. 1., you get 1. 2. 3. That qualifies for your condition, and yet, that's how Markdown works.

Comment: See, my motivation is that I am so accustomed to `)` that I write the post with `)` and then need to go and change every single `)` to `.` So perhaps just the Markdown  accepting it would be enough. I will reduce the suggestion.

Comment: @OndraŽižka Well, conversely, if I were started to write `)` everywhere instead of `.` I'd be quite unsettled :) It seems hard to acquire any evidence that more people would prefer the parenthesis. I could agree with customizing the markdown renderer to consider ) as a dot, if it doesn't break parsing. However, most markdown in use in most sites I consult uses the dot, so I question wether or not that is really future proof.

Comment: Right, maybe the feature request should be targetted to Markdown rather than SO.

Answer (score 4):

This is part of [the CommonMark specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.27/#list-items):

> An [ordered list marker](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.27/#ordered-list-marker) is a sequence of 1–9 arabic digits (0-9), followed by either a . character or a ) character. (The reason for the length limit is that with 10 digits we start seeing integer overflows in some browsers.)

One of [the contributors](http://commonmark.org/) being [Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) (aka balpha). [He suggested that Stack Exchange would switch back in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238957/will-commonmark-be-adopted-for-se).

Having said that I (UK) am now more used to a `.` as a list indicator rather than a `)`, which was common a few decades ago.

Comment: The UK voted they are not Europe. (Sorry, couldn't resist.) But you're right, it's more local than Europe.

Comment: @OndraŽižka The UK is still a part of Europe until the official leave deadline. (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Comment: Despite what some citizens of my country would prefer @Script, we'll remain part of Europe for at least a few millennia after leaving the EU!